# How to query a database from a Kafka processor?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to create an Account Management service using `Kafka` and `Kafka Streams`.

`SignupRequest` messages are placed on a `signup-requests` topic, and the first processor in the stream consuming that topic must check email uniqueness first, that is where the problems start, I am thinking on 2 possibilities but I am just a newbie ...

The first one would be to create a `KTable` on the `accounts` topic, so I can check email uniqueness with it. But I read that messages in a topic have a time to leave, after which they are deleted. So if an account with the checked email was created a long time ago greater than the configured time to leave, then it should not be present it the `KTable`, and my verification will be compromised.

The second option would be to query the database where the accounts are really persisted directly, but how to do async operations inside a `kafka` processor ? and is it a good practice ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're definition of a "normal database" is, but the default implementation of the persistent KTable is backed by RocksDB, a KV-Store. Or you can use Kafka Connect to dump the topics into a database which more closely suits your query patterns

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will explore that topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that messages in a topic have a time to leave, after which they are deleted.

You can define retention based on time (or size of a topic), but can you also configure a topic as **compacted**. This is a special retention option which means that for every *key*, the latest message is always preserved—regardless of when it was received. Compacted topics are therefore great for topics that sit behind KTables.

Comment: So with compacted topics and KTables, kafka can be seen and used as a normal database ?

Comment: Kafka will there for be the data hub of everything